# Configuring Symfony 2 at Runtime

Tags: php, symfony, apache-zookeeper

I'm creating web services for my company using Symfony2. Our company uses a centralized configuration service (Zookeeper/etcd) to manage configuration information for our services. Such as connection/host information for MySQL, Redis, Memcached, etc. The configuration is subject to change randomly through out the day. For instance when MySQL servers are added or removed from our database cluster. So hard coding the configuration in yml/xml is not possible.

So I'm looking for a way to modify the config.yml values when the application boots. Some of the values in the config will be static. For instance Twig and Switfmailer configurations, but other values for Doctrine and Redis need to be set on the fly.

The configuration values cannot be determined until the Symfony application boots, and the values cannot be cached or compiled. I've tried a few things to hook into the boot process and modify the configuration, but nothing works.

Additional Information

An example of the architecture I'm dealing with is described here: http://aredko.blogspot.com/2013/10/coordination-and-service-discovery-with.html Along with services like MySQL and Redis, we also need to discover our own RESTful services. Zookeeper is being used as a service discovery agent. The location (host name) and exact configuration for the services aren't known until runtime/boot.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to [write a custom Config implementation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/index.html) that checks your upstream settings?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to take a look at [**OpenSkyRuntimeConfigBundle**](https://github.com/opensky/OpenSkyRuntimeConfigBundle).

The bundle allows you to replace traditional container parameters (that you usually write to `parameters.yml`) with some logic. This provides you a way to make a query to Zookeeper to check the latest configuration variables and inject them to Symfony2 services without a need to rebuild the container.

As you can write the logic in any possible way, you can also implement local cache for the parameters. ZK reads are performant but always require a network round-trip. If performance is important for you, utilize a cache here too.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't even consider running Symfony 2 without a cache if you care about performance.

It sounds like you've not quite identified the best way to compose your infrastructure whilst scaling things up / down. It's hard to be specific without knowing more about the bigger picture, but how about pointing the Symfony 2 db config to a proxy server, and manage the routing at the network level. The app then stays blissfully ignorant of the churn of db servers...

Comment: I'm not suggesting the Symfony caching/compiling be turned off. I'm pointing out that using a compiler pass solutions won't work. Modifying configuration values (if only for the duration of a request) shouldn't be impossible. Configuring Doctrine to use a custom factory class would do the trick.

Comment: If you aren't suggesting the caching be turned off, you may want to reword "...the values cannot be cached or compiled."... Also, I'm not suggesting it's impossible to solve at the app level, but that doing so seems to be making the problem harder than it could be. There must be a more sensible approach than trying to make part of the stack's long-term cache un-cacheable. You didn't previously mention compiler passes at all; what have already you tried re. Doctrine config?

Comment: I'm using the "wrapper_class" option for Doctrine to modify the connection parameters at runtime. That solution works fine, but I was hoping to find a one-size-fits-all solution. What I'm trying to do here is very common (see http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/02/04/service-discovery-in-the-cloud/). Using a proxy server doesn't help because even the proxy server hosts need to be "discovered" at runtime, and Symfony configuration would need to be updated.